# Google Calendar API authorization working on localhost but not on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I want to use the Google Calendar API for my Django application.
I have followed the instructions here: https://karenapp.io/articles/how-to-automate-google-calendar-with-python-using-the-calendar-api/

I have also added the redirect uri's in Google API - seems like a browser tries to open up on the server side (as it does on local, but I am unable to manipulate it as the browser from the server side does not show up). In the terminal I do see "Please visit this URL to authorize this application: [https://accounts.google.com/..."](https://accounts.google.com/...%22)

Any ideas on what I can do?

Code in views.py:

```
import datetime
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'path_to_file/credentials.json'

def get_calendar_service():
   creds = None

   if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
       with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
           creds = pickle.load(token)

   if not creds or not creds.valid:
       if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
           creds.refresh(Request())
       else:
           flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
               CREDENTIALS_FILE, SCOPES)
           creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

       with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
           pickle.dump(creds, token)

   service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
   return service
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are having is that you are using installed app flow.

```
 flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
               CREDENTIALS_FILE, SCOPES)
           creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

This code was designed for use with installed applications, therefore running your code will open the web browser window on the machine that it is currently running on.

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow

# Use the client_secret.json file to identify the application requesting
# authorization. The client ID (from that file) and access scopes are required.
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'])

# Indicate where the API server will redirect the user after the user completes
# the authorization flow. The redirect URI is required. The value must exactly
# match one of the authorized redirect URIs for the OAuth 2.0 client, which you
# configured in the API Console. If this value doesn't match an authorized URI,
# you will get a 'redirect_uri_mismatch' error.
flow.redirect_uri = 'https://www.example.com/oauth2callback'

# Generate URL for request to Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
# Use kwargs to set optional request parameters.
authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
    # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
    # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
    access_type='offline',
    # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
    include_granted_scopes='true')
```