# How to get Google Calendar API working in production to create an event

Tags: python, django, google-calendar-api

**Problem I'm trying to solve:** Using Google Calendar API to create a calendar event. It works on locahost but not in production following the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events). I'm looking for a solution to get it working in production.

**What I've tried:** I've spent a long time looking at solutions on here including this popular one: [Google Calendar API authorization working on localhost but not on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541162/google-calendar-api-authorization-working-on-localhost-but-not-on-heroku/69541263#69541263) but for me I'm not using pickle. I also attempted all the relevant changes in the answer in relation to my code but I still could not get it to work. I have also made sure that my API console includes the relevant permissions.

**What's happening:**
Terminal logs are showing that my code attempts to open a browser on the server machine "Please visit this URL to authorize this application" instead of popping up a browser window for the user. This is most likely because my first `try` block is failing - which I think is where the problem lies.

Please also note I have replaced my redirect URL in the code below for privacy reasons to `myurl.com/calendar/`. The redirect is simply set to the same page where I am running the code from.

**Google API Code:**

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'] 
# I also tried ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def create_calendar_event():

creds = None

if os.path.exists('../token.json'):
  creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('../token.json', SCOPES)
  print("Obtained credentials")

# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.

if not creds or not creds.valid:
  if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
    creds.refresh(Request())
  else:
    try:

      ## This is the production flow ##

      flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file('/secrets/secret-location/credentials.json', SCOPES)
      flow.redirect_uri = "myurl.com/calendar/"
      authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(access_type='offline', include_granted_scopes='true')

    except:
      print("Could not obtain credentials in production mode")

    try:

      ## This is the localhost/testing flow ##

      flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            '../credentials.json', SCOPES)
      print("Obtained Google Credentials from local file")
      creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
  
      with open('../token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

    except:
      print("Could not obtain credentials in localhost flow")
  
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# remainder of code to create event quite bulky so removed, 
# at this point the Google popup should ask for sign in.
```

Comment: went through this a few months ago. Comparing my project to yours... What happens if you add prompt='consent' after access_type = "offline"

Comment: Thanks for helping. I just tried that so it looks like this: `authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(access_type='offline', prompt='consent', include_granted_scopes='true')` but to no avail. Perhaps you could share a link to your code if this is public?

Comment: I posted my login and callback code in this pastie link.  issue could be in your callback.  also notice you are not redirecting the user to your authorization URL.  Hope this helps. I understand the struggle, had to piece this together from a bunch of different examples and trial by error.  I save my credentials to the database, versus using the file.  its a small project for myself and some colleagues.  http://pastie.org/p/6UZQdUrnwiYnsrH6nIWAXu

Comment: Am I missing something here with the redirect? I simply want the user to return to the same page (as my view for this page deals with the response). The same page is saved as an Authorised redirect URI in my Google console. By adding `print(authorization_url)` I am able to open the auth link and validate my application but for some reason it wont popup normally for the user, only in the console. Popups are not being blocked either.

Comment: is your user not logging in with google at some other point?  at the point of adding something to their calendar, they should already be logged in and you should be authenticating with a refresh token.  If they are not logged in, then they should probably be going through the whole log in process anyway

Comment: Nope, I have a 'create event' button as such and was hoping this would trigger the login like it does when using the `InstalledAppFlow` class on localhost testing.

Comment: the only way I could trigger the pop up is by using js - open.window().  in my case, i would need a js function to check to see if there are creds, if not, open.window(link to google sign in view)    I tried to trigger it from refreshing a view after deleting my creds and it would do the same thing you are describing - I could see that it would print my authorization url, but wouldn't pop up a window.    i never ran into this because my users log in with google or microsoft

Comment: Hi Olney, you said you wanted to "trigger the login like it does when using the InstalledAppFlow class on localhost testing." Did you succeed in that? Cos I am trying the same.